# I made a profile with Colorchecker Camera Calibration software. How to import the .icm file for use in Camera Raw?

Tags: photoshop, color, color-management, adobe-camera-raw, icc-profile

I used the [Colorchecker Camera Calibration](https://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?ID=938&Action=Support&SoftwareID=2030) software with a TIFF photo of the Colorchecker I did with my camera. This software detected the Colorchecker successfully and produced a .icm file as output.

**Then I'd like to use this .icm profile inside Photoshop/CameraRaw. How to do this?**

I don't find the option to load a .icm neither in `Basic > Profile` near in `Calibration` tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in the Adobe Camera Raw or Lightroom, the way that camera characterisation is done is via custom .dcp profiles, those are created with the Adobe [DNG Profile Editor](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html#resources). The [documentation](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/DNGProfile_EditorDocumentation.pdf) explains how to create them:

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Comment: Thank you. It works indeed when using DNG files as input (after putting the .dcp file in the right folder, for Win: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw\CameraProfiles`) ; the color calibration is slightly different than the one obtained with "Colorchecker Camera Calibration" software. (PS: when opening JPG or TIFF files with CameraRaw, the .dcp profile made with DNG Profile Editor doesn't appear. So the only solution is to use RAW)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my conclusions for now after further research:

- Using Xrite's "Colorchecker Camera Calibration" software in TIFF mode produces `.icm`  files. It probably cannot be used easily in Photoshop (?), or at least not in the normal CameraRaw workflow.
- Using Xrite's "Colorchecker Camera Calibration" software in DNG mode produces `.dcp`  profiles that can be easily used in CameraRaw (when opening DNG files only; when opening JPG/TIFF files in CameraRaw this `.dcp` profile doesn't appear).

See [How to use a Xrite Colorchecker on a specific image to get the right colors?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/112887/how-to-use-a-xrite-colorchecker-on-a-specific-image-to-get-the-right-colors) for more details.